# Hibernate doesn't create table that implements Serializable interface?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I have small project with Spring Data, MVC and Web Flow. Also I have 2 entities that I use in Spring Web Flow, so they MUST implement  Serializable interface, but I noticed that Hibernate doesn't create tables, that implement it, for proving it I  just copied my entity, removed "implements Serializable"  created new class and pasted the entity code there, the new table was created. How it works ? How to create table from entity that implement Serializable, is it possible at all ?

The entities code:

```
@Table(name = "users")
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "idUsers")
private int id;
@Column(name = "login")
@Size(min = 3, max = 15,message = "Неправильний розмір")
@NotEmpty(message = "Не може бути пустим!")
private String login;
@Size(min = 6, max = 21,message = "Неправильний розмір")
@NotEmpty(message = "Не може бути пустим!")
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;
@NotNull(message = "Не може бути пустим!")
@Column(name = "email")
private String email;
@Column(name = "photo")
private String path;
@Column(name = "about")
private String about;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}



@OneToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        mappedBy = "user",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
)
private Set<CommentsToBook> commentsToBooks;

public Set<CommentsToBook> getCommentsToBooks() {
    return commentsToBooks;
}

public void setCommentsToBooks(Set<CommentsToBook> commentsToBooks) {
    this.commentsToBooks = commentsToBooks;
}

public Set<BookOrder> getOrders() {
    return orders;
}

public void setOrders(Set<BookOrder> orders) {
    this.orders = orders;
}

@OneToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        mappedBy = "user",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
)
private Set<BookOrder> orders;


public String getPath() {
    return path;
}

public String getAbout() {
    return about;
}

public void setAbout(String about) {
    this.about = about;
}

public void setPath(String path) {
    this.path = path;
}

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
}
```

And the second one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "booook_order")
public class BookOrder implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;
@Column(name = "bank_card")
private String bankCardId;
@Column(name = "user_name")
private String custName;

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}
@ManyToMany(fetch =  FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "book", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "id")
},inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "idlibrary")})
private Set<Book> booksList;


@Column(name ="novaposhta-vid")
private String NPVid;

public String getNPVid() {
    return NPVid;
}

public void setNPVid(String NPVid) {
    this.NPVid = NPVid;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

@Column(name = "city")
private String city;

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "idUsers")
private User user;

public String getCustName() {
    return custName;
}

public void setCustName(String custName) {
    this.custName = custName;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Set<Book> getBooksList() {
    return booksList;
}

public void setBooksList(Set<Book> booksList) {
    this.booksList = booksList;
}

public String getBankCardId() {
    return bankCardId;
}

public void setBankCardId(String bankCardId) {
    this.bankCardId = bankCardId;
}
}
```

Comment: i don't think this is causing a problem `implements Serializable`, just try with same entity removing `implements Serializable`

Comment: I removed `implements Serializable` and Hibernate doesn't create the table . But if i create new class with the same code it works. Why ?

Comment: new class in same package? or different package?

Comment: all entity classes are in the same package

Comment: then check there is already a table `users` in DB and also what is your `auto-ddl` value?

Comment: Yes, you were right! In my DataBase name 'users' was already taken but i updated the question and added another entity that doesn't creates, it's name is free in Data Base

Comment: I think in my second entity's code isn't valid? can you please say what went wrong ? Logs dont show me anything